# Need an SQL query to connect the two tables in the different databases but the databases are in different server

Tags: sql-server-2005

Need an SQL query to connect the two tables that are in two different database,the databases are located in different servers.I am using SQL 2005.

Answer (score 0):

You need (and should be googling) Linked Servers

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx